# Как вернуться из второго цикла к прошлому?

Tags: python-3.x

```
While True:
    a = input()
    if a == 1:
        While True:
            b = input()
```

Какой оператор нужно применить для возврата в первый цикл?

Comment: при каком-то условии или после первого `input` ?

Comment: При каком-то условии.

Answer (score 3):

Оператор [break](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) нужно применить.

```
While True:
    a = input()
    if a == 1:
        While True:
            b = input()
            if b == '2':
                break
```

P.S. Условие в вашем примере работать не будет.

Comment: break закрывает программу, а мне нужно сделать так что бы завершился второй цикл и начал работать первый.

Comment: `break` не закрывает программу, если расположен в нужном блоке.

Comment: Тогда что нужно сделать в примере что бы break не закрывал программу?

Answer (score 0):

Условие выхода из вложенного цикла, нужно указывать на входе в цикл, тогда программа вернется в основной цикл

```py
    a = 0
    b = 0

    while True:
        a = int(input('Введите a: '))
        if a == 1:
            while b != 2:
                b = int(input('Введите b: '))

        if a == 1 and b == 2:
            print(a, b)

    # дальше какой-то код после которого условие выхода из основного цикла
```